# CDI instance selection by annotation not found after migration to JBoss EAP 7

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cdi

I am having an ear file with (among others) the following contents running on a JBoss EAP 7.0.3:
common.jar
protocol-v4.jar

In common.jar I have the following code (partial):

MessageServiceImpl.java:

```
@Any
@Inject
private Instance<MessageMapper<M>> mappers; // M -> SimpleMessage

// ...
MessageMapper<M> mapper = findInstance(mappers, new MapperType.Literal(messageType, parameters.getProtocolVersion()), "message mapper");

// inside findInstance:
Instance<T> candidate = instance.select(annotationLiteral);
```

First the result: `candidate` above has isUnsatisfied() to true.

Now the implementation is inside protocol-v4.jar:

```
@MapperType(messageType = MessageType.HANDSHAKE, version = Protocol.VERSION)
public class HandshakeMessageMapper extends AbstractPositiveMessageMapper {
```

`AbstractPositiveMessageMapper` in its chain somewhere implements `MessageMapper<SimpleMessage>`

I used to use this in JBoss EAP 6.4.10, but now with JBoss EAP 7.0.3 it is suddenly unsatisfied. What am I missing? Was it a bug, that it used to work before? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I have started using the BeanManager to explore a bit more what is going on. This is right before the `instance.select`:

```
Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {});

for(Bean<?> bean : beans) {
    if(bean.getBeanClass().getName().contains("v104.mapper.Handshake")) {
        for(Annotation annotation : bean.getQualifiers()) {
            if(annotation.annotationType() == MapperType.class) {
                MapperType mapper = (MapperType) annotation;
                logger.info("Type: {}, Version: {}", mapper.messageType(), mapper.version());
            } else {
                logger.info("Qualifier: {}", annotation.annotationType());
            }
        }
        logger.info("Bean: " + bean);
    }
}
```

This works and shows my HandshakeMessageMapper as a bean with the correct qualifiers (@Any and @MapperType(value & protocol)).

If however I change the `getBeans` to: `beanManager.getBeans(MessageMapper.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {});` no beans can be found. So for some reason the `BeanManager` does not consider my `HandshakeMessageMapper` to be a bean that can offer the interface `MessageMapper`

Comment: hi, I'm facing the very same issue with Jakarta 8 (CDI 2.0), and just like you I have all annotations in place (tried also with @ApplicationScoped in conjunction with @Typed). Did you manage to solve? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One significant change from cdi 1.0 to cdi 1.1 was how beans are discoverd. The new default is that only annotated beans are discovered.

So you have two options (i am aware of):

- Add `@Dependent` annotations to the beans you want.
- Set the bean-discovery-mode to "all" in the `beans.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

For more details you might want to check out https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/default_cdi_enablement_in_java

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also read about this before and used the @Dependent annotation in one of my earlier tests, which didn't help. I have now also tried changing the bean-discovery-mode for protocol-v4 to all but it is still unable to find the bean using the `select` on the instance.